# Excel: Hiding all rows and columns that don't contain coloured cells

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro that when activated, will hide all columns and rows that don't have a cell formatted to a certain colour. I adapted a similar sub for columns with content only but this is another step extra that my brain can't seem to get around this morning. For reference, this is what I used to hide all columns that did not have content:

```
Sub HideCols()
Dim LC As Integer, j As Integer
Dim LR As Integer, curCnt As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim Data As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LC = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For j = 3 To LC
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
    curCnt = 0
    Data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC))
    For k = 1 To LR
       If Rows(k).Hidden = False And Data(k, j) <> "" Then _
       curCnt = curCnt + 1
    Next k
    Columns(j).Hidden = curCnt < 2
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If there's a cell with the specified color, do you want to hide the row it's in, or the column (or both)?

Comment: I want to NOT hide them, if that makes sense. I want anything without the specified formatting to be hidden; but yes, both rows and columns @BruceWayne

Comment: I just recorded a macro filtering by color and got this: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor` Maybe you can also record a macro and easily get the code you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to hide all the row and column of a cell that is black. I'm sure you can modify to fit your need.

```
Sub hide_cell()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A2:d10")
    For Each MyCell In Rng
        If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            MyCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```